# How to use http:// in https:// using iframe?

Tags: http, iframe, https

my website is ssl-enabled secure containg https://
Now i want to add a website link in my webpage using iframe which is in http://

How can i use it, Here problem is with http:// not working in https:// using iframe.

PLease give a solution

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, in many modern browsers because it is a major security issue. There's a workaround though, you can proxy the content via HTTPS. You have to create a something on HTTPS that fetches the unsecured content for you and passes it over TLS to the end user in the iframe. This, however, is not as trivial as it looks. Just fetching the content might not be enough, because the user might want/need to POST something back. And it's not just the content, but the headers too if you need to support cookies. And when the content you served over your proxy solution loads stuff via HTTP you end up with a mixed content warning.